# Unable to get Auth::user()->id

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

I have two controllers; `AuthController` and `CheckoutController` now my `AuthController` handles User **Logins** and **Registrations**, when the user logins i am able to check their logged in status and get their `user_id` from the `AuthController`.

However when i try to do this in my `CheckoutController` i always have `Auth::user()->id` returning this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

.

No matter what i do it's always the same, i have looked online for solutions but haven't found anything about this.

I just realized something though, my `AuthController` and `CheckoutController` are in **2 different namespaces** and i am wondering if this could be the cause/reason.

This is my login code:

```
/**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  LoginRequest  $request`
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['code' => 300, 'message' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        $url_parts = parse_url($request->url());
        $host_parts = explode('.', $url_parts['host']);

        if ($host_parts[0] == "admin")
        {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            if (!$user->is('administrator'))
            {
                Auth::logout();
                return response()->json(['error' => 'You Are Not Authorized!']);
            }
        }

        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you're referring to from `AuthController` and `CheckoutController`.

Comment: If you're using Laravel's default Auth , In other name space simply use \Auth::user()->id make sure user logged in too

Comment: Alright i have added my login code now.

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces wont matter for this, It seems like you may be using the wrong method to log the user in, are you using Auth::once instead of Auth::attempt ?

Comment: Do you have a jwt auth middleware setup to re-login on each request?

Comment: Re-login on each request? Am i supposed to do that?

Comment: Okay i think i get what you mean, you see this particular controller method can be accessed by both registered and un-registered users so i didn't add a middleware to it.

Comment: Ahh so you will just need to do an auth check and handle non authenticated visitors differently

Comment: If you just need the user id but its not required then you can also use Auth::id

Comment: Auth:id also always returns null even if the user is logged in hence the reason for my post

Comment: Try $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate() if the user is logged in the you your be able to get the id, otherwise user will equal false

Comment: Thanks you gave me an idea of what i was doing wrong, found a solution here that appears to work though : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/103 :)

Comment: nice, he even created a middleware just for this